# How do I use the random-seed command in Netlogo to ensure runs of my model have the reproducible results?

Tags: netlogo, random-seed

I am currently working on a model that uses randomness in a few places. Since I want the runs of this model to have results that are reproducible, I would like the drawn numbers to be the same with each re-run of the model.

I have tried using the `random-seed` command, since I read that this is how to do this in Netlogo. I first just put in a number, so: `random-seed 1520`. After that did not work I tried the `new-seed`reporter. I first tried: `let my-seed new-seed set random-seed my-seed`, since that is how it was in the code example. I am using Netlogo 6.3.0, by the way. I expected the inclusion of the random seed to ensure that the model would come to the same results each time I pressed setup and go, instead of fluctuating like it did before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`random-seed <number>` works fine. I think the issue you are facing here is located somewhere else, but without more information, I can't help. Are you sure that you set the random-seed in your setup procedure correctly?

Besides the [dictonary](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/random-seed.html) you also find help in the [programming guide](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#random-numbers). Furthermore there is a [random-seed example model](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/models/RandomSeedExample) in the models library.

This code works fine:

```
to setup
  clear-all
  random-seed 1
  repeat 5 [print random 100]
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I think I know what the problem is now. I did not understand that the use-new-seed procedure was the setup procedure of that model. So, if I actually put the procedure where I add the random seed into the setup I should be fine. Thanks!

Comment: exactly, basically when you set a new `random-seed` a sequence of "random" numbers is set. These numbers will be taken one by one every time a random number is needed. So if you want to restart, you need to reset to the same random-seed to make sure that you start from the beginning of that sequence.